# query for Time Stamp in mongo

Tags: mongodb-query

I have the following requirement,where I need to fetch the data using the timestamp. The time stamp has Date and Time.I want to fetch only the Date.Please find the screen shot attached.I wrote the query as

```
db.General_Liability.aggregate({
    $project : {
        new_time_stamp : {$substr : ["$session.Datestamp",0, 2]}
    }
});
```

On querying the new time stamp is showing as empty.Please help me with this

[image]

Comment: what do you meant with "On querying the new time stamp is show as empty" , I think the projection should be 0,9, but I dont get your point of then query, you meant you have another aggregation operation in the pipeline ?

Comment: sorry to confuse you.I want to query the data based on the date.My datetime has both date and time.I used a substring to fetch only the date.The above query what i wrote is not throwing any error by new time stamp filed is shown as blank.